# Trigger with multiple WHEN conditions

Tags: postgresql, triggers, ddl, boolean-expression

How do I include the columns I need to monitor? I.e. instead of one `WHEN` condition I want to have 3 `WHEN` conditions:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER freeradius.insert_into_day_summations 
     BEFORE INSERT ON freeradius.day_guiding_usage
     FOR EACH ROW 
     WHEN (OLD.col1 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.col1)
     WHEN (OLD.col2 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.col2)
     WHEN (OLD.col3 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.col3)
EXECUTE procedure update_sessioninfo();
```

Comment: Did you just try combining them with `OR`? The documentation says this is just a boolean condition. Should work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Form a single expression with `OR` or `AND` - depending on whether you want to trigger when *all* conditions are met or when either *one* condition is met:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_day_summations  -- see below
BEFORE UPDATE ON freeradius.day_guiding_usage
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (OLD.col1 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.col1
   OR OLD.col2 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.col2
   OR OLD.col3 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.col3)
EXECUTE procedure update_sessioninfo();
```

It's just a boolean expression, can involve all columns of the row.
**However**, your expressions only make sense for **`UPDATE`**, not for `INSERT`. There is no `OLD` record for inserts. [The manual on `CREATE TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html):

> ***`condition`***
>
> A Boolean expression that determines whether the trigger function will
>   actually be executed. If `WHEN` is specified, the function will only be
>   called if the ***`condition`*** returns `true`. In `FOR EACH ROW` triggers, the
>   `WHEN` condition can refer to columns of the old and/or new row values
>   by writing `OLD.`***`column_name`*** or `NEW.`***`column_name`*** respectively. Of course,
>   `INSERT` triggers cannot refer to `OLD` and `DELETE` triggers cannot refer to `NEW`.

And the trigger name itself cannot be schema-qualified. Quoting the manual once more:

> ***`name`***
>
> The name to give the new trigger. This must be distinct from the name of any other trigger for the same table. The
>   **name cannot be schema-qualified**

**Bold** emphasis mine.

Answer (score -1):

TG_WHEN

Data type text; a string of BEFORE, AFTER, or INSTEAD OF, depending on the trigger's definition.

here is a link may use

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html