# Update a column in a function using plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql, database-trigger

I am writing a trigger function in PostgreSQL 9.5. When a column named `action_flag` is updated from `FALSE` to `TRUE`, a function is called.

If `order_num` is in some table, then I want the update from `FALSE` to `TRUE` to proceed.

Else, if `order_num` is in some other table, then I want to raise an exception and prevent the update from happening.

I need assistance writing the `UPDATE` within my `IF` statement. The `ELSEIF` part functions as expected.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_ingredient_availability()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$Body$
BEGIN
    if (OLD.order_num IN ( SELECT  order_num
                   FROM    can_prep_m_orders )) THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'This is a notice.';
        --UPDATE meal_order
        --SET actioned_flag=TRUE
        --WHERE order_num=OLD.order_NUM;

        --EXECUTE  'UPDATE  meal_order
            -- SET   actioned_flag=TRUE
             --WHERE     order_num=$1' 
             --USING OLD.order_num;
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSEIF (OLD.order_num IN ( SELECT  order_num
                        FROM    cannot_prep_m_orders )) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Missing ingredients. Cannot prepare order number %.',
                OLD.order_num;
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;    
$Body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_ingredient_availability()
   RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM can_prep_m_orders
         WHERE  order_num = NEW.order_num  -- NEW !?
         ) THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'This is a notice.';

      -- do nothing, let original UPDATE proceed

      RETURN NEW;   -- let UPDATE proceed
   END IF;

   IF EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM cannot_prep_m_orders
         WHERE  order_num = NEW.order_num  -- NEW!?
         ) THEN

      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Missing ingredients. Cannot prepare order number %.', NEW.order_num;
                                       -- I assume you want to mention the *new* order_num?
   END IF;

   RETURN NULL;  -- cancel original UPDATE in all other cases
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Related:

- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists - SELECT INTO boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892233/pl-pgsql-checking-if-a-row-exists-select-into-boolean/11892796#11892796)

Also, add a `WHEN` clause to your trigger to run these checks when

> `action_flag` is updated from `FALSE` to `TRUE`

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger_name
BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.action_flag AND NOT OLD.action_flag)
EXECUTE procedure check_ingredient_availability();
```

Related:

- [Trigger with multiple WHEN conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360155/trigger-with-multiple-when-conditions/18360493#18360493)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Erwin. This was very helpful!

I didn't know that RETURN NEW; is what allowed the update to proceed.

Comment: @Pizzas: [Consider reading this chapter of the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)